# oracle sql performance in large dataset

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, spring-data, large-data

I have a query like this.

I use Jpa and only retrieve the first 50 results but it takes too long a time on my table with 2 million records.

How can I increase performance?

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION 
WHERE
   (trunc(REQUEST_TIME,'MI') between to_date('1390/01/01 01:01','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI','nls_calendar=persian') 
                                 and to_date('1396/11/01 01:01','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI','nls_calendar=persian'))
and  CUSTOMER like '%123%'
and  (case when (ERROR_CODE is not null and ERROR_CODE <> 200) then -1 
           when (ERROR_CODE is not null and ERROR_CODE =200) then 200 
       else 0 end =0)
and (URL = 'url1')
and ( SOURCE like '%123%')
and ( ERROR_CODE=200) 
and ( REQUEST_ID like '%1234%')
```

Comment: Your conditions on `ERROR_CODE` are contradictory.  The `CASE` expression, in particular, should never have a match unless `ERROR_CODE` is `NULL`.  But that is then filtered out by a later condition.

Comment: what indexes do you have on the table?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `TRUNC` function from here, it is needeless but prevents RDBMS from using an index on column `REQUEST_TIME` (if there is any):

```
   (trunc(REQUEST_TIME,'MI') between .......
```

---

Remove `ERROR_CODE is not null` condition from here, if `ERROR_CODE <> 200` or `ERROR_CODE =200`, then it always must be NOT NULL:

```
case when (ERROR_CODE is not null  and ERROR_CODE <> 200)
then -1 when (ERROR_CODE is not null and ERROR_CODE =200)
then 200 else 0 end =0)
```

If you simplify the above condition, you'll get:

```
case when ERROR_CODE <> 200 then -1 
     when ERROR_CODE =200 then 200 
     else 0 
end =0
```

If you examine the simplified condition above, it's obvious that it's checking only for the "else 0" part, so it can be further simplified into just:

```
ERROR_CODE IS NULL
```

but since there is another condition in your query `and ( ERROR_CODE=200)`, the first condition excludes another one `and ( ERROR_CODE=200)` so I think that you are not showing us a real query in the question. I would simply remove this condition because it's most likely a logic error.

---

After the above simplifications you'll get:

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION 
WHERE
  REQUEST_TIME between to_date('1390/01/01 01:01','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI','nls_calendar=persian') 
                   and to_date('1396/11/01 01:01','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI','nls_calendar=persian')
  and  CUSTOMER like '%123%'
  and (URL = 'url1')
  and ( SOURCE like '%123%')
  and ( ERROR_CODE=200) and( REQUEST_ID like '%1234%')
```

Now make sure that there is an index created on `REQUEST_TIME`, if not, then create it and verify a performance of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that this is not an ad-hoc(rarely used) type query.
Define a functional index on `trunc(REQUEST_TIME,'MI')` as column.